# Textbox Cut Off

Tags: html, css

I feel like this is something that's really simple to fix, but I'm just too dumb to figure it out, but I've been Googling for a long time to figure this out. The textbox on the bottom of my page is getting cut off for some reason. I think it has to do with how the body div is set up. Also, if someone could tell me how to get my textarea the same size as the main div, that'd really be nice. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jRCy3/)

HTML

```
    <div id="body">
<div id="main">
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <hr />
    <p>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</p>
</div>
    <div id="controls"><form action="#" method="POST">Enter a Comment: <br /><textarea sizable="false"></textarea><br /><input type="submit" value="submit" /></form></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#main {
    background-color:white;
    position:relative;
    min-height:300px;
    padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
    border-left: 1px grey solid;
    border-right: 1px grey solid;
    border-bottom: 1px grey solid;
}
#main p {
    font-size:20px;
    word-wrap:break-word;
}
#header {
    background-color: #C0C0C0;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid grey;

}
html, body{
    height: 100%;
}
#body {
margin-left:75px;   
margin-right:75px;
margin-bottom:125px;
margin-top:0;
}
#controls {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    width:90%;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 0;
} #controls form textarea {
    resize: false;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just removed this one property from the CSS tab

```
#controls {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

and it worked! You can see the full textarea now.

Here is the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/afzaal_ahmad_zeeshan/jRCy3/2/

Comment: Thank you for that, but what's odd is, even though it works on that example, it doesn't seem to be working on my actually page. I don't see why.

Comment: Have you tried to replace the CSS there too? Try to hard refresh the browser page i.e. Press CTRL + SHIFT + F5 to refresh the page and reload the CSS contents from the file rather than the cached service.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but I just tried that and it didn't help. I could put the full page on JSFiddle

Answer (score 0):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jRCy3/3/)

```
#controls {
        position: absolute;
        display: inline-block;
        width:90%;
        height: 100px;
                 //removed 'overflow:hidden' property
        z-index: 0;
    }
```